# Vbs Message Box Alternative [C++]

Tags: c++, vbscript

I'm trying to output a oftstream with a text on it that can run as a Message box

But I would like to know if there is an alternative to do this witouht .vbs.

If it can be done with .exe or another extension.

Comment: convert your .vbs script to .exe executable using vbsedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the sad realiations for budding programmers is discovering that Windows has no way to just output an information GUI message in short DOS one-liners. VBS is your best bet, but I'm pretty sure you don't get ctype "streams" with it, and you'll have to look elsewhere anyway.

What you want delves into the murky waters of full-on Windows programming. I can't figure out from your oftstream whether you only have university level C++ knowledge. If so, Windows / C++ GUI is totally not going to be covered and you'll have to "learn" about windows specific .h files, .lib files and windows-aware IDE like code::blocks, and tons of other things. If you've done Windows dev before and aren't afraid of completely alien function calls and a lack of void main(), then head over to http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson04.htm and http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_1.shtm.

Extension changes don't help you...you couldn't just rename my post to exe and have it execute, for example. You need a target language that you know WELL, or if this is not a school project, then look into "automation tools" like AutoIt and others, and prepare to depend on their runtimes being on every computer that your code expects to run. For portability, the easiest thing is to just google a few VBS functions and combine them into your desired short script (but you're trying to avoid vb).

Comment: lol thats true. Ill check links bro

Comment: really not clear what you want exactly, but you can run vbs as a console application and capture text output to file using "cscript.exe foo.vbs > capture.txt"